# calling a rest endpoint in a springboot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

which is better alternative for calling REST endpoint in springboot application, calling REST endpoints using WebClient or calling REST endpoints using RestTemplate ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebClient vs RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974757/webclient-vs-resttemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring’s documentation recommends using WebClient, but that’s only a valid recommendation for reactive apps. If you aren’t writing a reactive app, use OpenFeign instead. Like anything else in software, it fits well for some cases, but might complicate things for others. Choosing WebClient to implement the REST endpoint calls is strongly coupled to making your app reactive

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate gives many advantages if you are using it from within Springboot application, i.e. in your server side to another part of your own app - sort of like an internal call. Because the RestTemplate "knows" all your entities and beans and so if you need to send over or receive an object which is known within your springboot application RestTemplate can map them automatically which is a very nice advantage. If you sending a request to some third party api and do not pass or receive your known entities RestTemplate is still a valid option but it just becomes just another Http client. Its just simply there as part of Springboot provided tools. But in this case you may use any other client as well.